# Javascript function skips statements

Tags: javascript, function

I have a simple function as follows:

```
function FUNCTION1() {
    document.getElementById('Preview1').innerHTML = ''){

    if (document.UserData.input1.value.length !== 0;
        var input1 = document.UserData.input1.value;


        document.getElementById('Preview1').innerHTML = '<div>Hello ' + input1 + '</div>';}

    }
```

I run the above script and everything is just fine.

Then I run another function to clear the div which has the form "UserData".

```
 document.getElementById('UserDataDiv').innerHTML = '';
```

And then I run the FUNCTION1 again, It brings up old value This value should not be there as div was cleared.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you defining `UserData`?

Comment: Your if statement is mangled for one thing.

Comment: `if (document.UserData.input1.value.length !== 0;` is a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just check that the string is empty instead of the length of the value: document.UserData.input1.value.length:

```
if (document.UserData.input1.value == '')
```

Oh, as someone else has pointed out, it also looks like there's an extra semi-colon at the end of your first line.

Comment: UserData is input tag in HTML

Comment: Rocket Hazmat, made an error when was creating a sample post. in original code the above line is fine